# cifs mount window share stopped working

Tags: mount, share

So I had a server 2003 windows share on a domain working on the RPi but the other day it stopped working. I checked with the system admin to see if anything had changed, and he had indeed made changes, but they were not affecting the RPi's ability to access the share, on the server it failed with "invalid username or password." After checking to make sure it would work on an Ubuntu machine, I determined it indeed was just a problem within the pi.

So here's the `/etc/fstab` line:

```
 //192.168.1.4/Music /mnt/music cifs sec=ntlmv2,credentials=/root/.credentials,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0
```

and in `/root/.credentials`

```
username=joesmith
password=joesmithpassword
domain=localdomain.com
```

where `joesmith`, `joesmithpassword`, and `localdomain.com` are valid username, password, and local domain

and yes I have double and triple checked their spelling and accuracy, but I continually get a `mount error(13): Permission denied` and on the server side it fails

Anyone have any idea why this would fail on the RPi but not ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I was reading the image a few times the card reader it disconnected, so sometime after that it had stopped working. I had an older version of the image that wasn't corrupt, and imaged the card with that and it works flawlessly. Remember to always safely eject your SD card, and don't use unreliable card readers with the RPi!